# toString but only if not null

Tags: java, null, tostring

Is there any utility available to easily get the string representation of an arbitrary object if it exists and keep it `null` if it was `null`?

For example

```
String result = null;
if (object != null) {
    result = object.toString();
}
```

but less verbose.

I have looked into `ObjectUtils` and `String.valueOf` but neither returns just `null` itself. Both return default strings, i.e. the empty string or the string `"null"` instead of just `null`.

Comment: You could just... use the string itself without any util? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Any problem with `myString == null`?

Comment: Sure, but doing a ternary is a lot of code bloat. I thought there would be something in commons akin to `object == null? null : object.toString()` guess I was wrong?

Comment: @Compass That ternary is a slower way to write `return string;`

Comment: guess I wasn't clear, it's not necessarily a string, it's any object...

Comment: You should change the title, which says "... if a **String** is null..."

Comment: Objects.toString(s, null)

Comment: The question is neither clear nor is there any use for others. As the comments show it is more than trivial.

Comment: I agree, but I was surprised something so common wasn't placed in, well, Commons...

Comment: Well, it is. `Objects` is an utility class for pretty much the most common stuff regarding arbitrary objects. And, as shown, it has the utility you want. If that is not enough, you can always create your own helper method.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you can use that ([`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) is here since JDK7):

```
Objects.toString(s, null); // return null if s is null, s.toString() otherwise
```

In fact, it works for every object.

Comment: `StringUtils.defaultString(s)` won't work, because it converts the value to an empty string, what I need is it to be null.

Comment: I think then `Objects.toString(o, null)` is the only option. Would have liked to avoid the extra param though.

Comment: You're right, but Objects.toString will more than likely work.

Comment: An upside of the extra param is that it makes it clear to readers that you're intentionally handling null, and purposefully returning `null` as the result when the value is null.  A lot of times null handling behavior is accidental and a source of bugs, so by using this approach, it's clear that you as the code writer (probably) thought through the null implications and chose that behavior.